# im new to programming need a little help understanding classes

Tags: python, class, csv

why does this not work ive wrote this code as a function and it works fine
but when i try to make it a method

```python
import csv
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
todayStr = str(today)

def query(self,q):
    self.q = q
    with open('rodata.csv','r')as r:
        reader = csv.reader(r)
        for row in reader:
            for field in row:
                if field == q:
                    print(row)

Logger = logger

run = True
while run:
    Logger.query(todayStr)
    run = False
```

I get this back:

```
TypeError: query() missing 1 required positional argument: 'q'
```

Comment: you need to define your class `class logger:` before `def query(self,q)`, then also add parenthesis to logger `Logger=logger()`

Answer (score 2):

To create a class first you need `class className`, in your case `logger`. Then you aren't iterating over each column/field of your row, you need to divide it up. And finally, you need to add parenthesis to your class creation.

```
import csv
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()

todayStr = str(today)

# add this line
class logger:
    def query(self,q):
        self.q = q
        with open('rodata.csv','r') as r:
            reader = csv.reader(r)
            for row in reader:
                # add this line, as row currently looks like ['timestamp a b c ...']
                row=row[0].split()
                for field in row:
                    if field == q:
                        print(row)
#add parenthesis
Logger = logger()


run = True
while run:
    Logger.query(todayStr)
    run = False
```

<sub>Something else to keep in mind is your `query` method is not currently returning anything.</sub>